# How to find out if a set must be reordered because the member used for sorting has been changed?

Tags: c++, stdmap

I found this code here to resort efficiently an element in a map:

```
std::map<int, MyClass> m{ {1, a}, {2, b} };
auto nodeHandler = m.extract(1);
nodeHandler.key() = 3;
m.insert(std::move(nodeHandler)); // { { 2, b }, { 3, a } }
```

However, I have something like this:

```
class MyClass
{
   int start;
   std::string name;
   MyClassSet* m_set[2];
};

class MyClassSet
{
public:
   typedef std::function<bool(MyClass*, MyClass*>) CmpFunc;
   MyClassSet(int listType, CmpFunc cmpFunc) : m_multiSet(cmpFunc) {}

private:
   std::multi_set<MyClass*, CmpFunc> m_multiSet;
};

static auto CmpByStart = [](const MyClass* left, const MyClass* right) -> bool
{
    return left->start < right->start;
}

static auto CmpByname = [](const MyClass* left, const MyClass* right) -> bool
{
    return left->name < right->name;
}
```

Now my problem is, that in many cases I could save the time - e.g. because name is changed, but at least one of the lists is sorted by start - and I want to find out if I really need to extract and insert the object again. It might be in a set which is compared by name, so there is no need to do this if I change the start value.

My question now is, what would be the most performant way to avoid unnecessary re-sorts? I only have a very ugly idea, to create two dummy objects, set everything to 0 or "" except the changed value. For this we set the old and new value and then we compare if it is equal by calling the comparison function 2 times. Really ugly.

Comment: i don't really understand what the "problem" is. You can apply the same 4 lines in your case. `insert` does tell you if the element was inserted or not. You could call `find` before, but that would be more expensive in case you actually need to insert the element

Comment: _"what would be the best way"_ What is your metric for _"best"_?

Comment: My problem is, that in many cases I don't need to remove and add the element again - because it was not the key - which is time consuming (i have to do it thousands of times unfortunately). So I would like to check if resorting is still needed. And the metric is the performance, as it currently is still timeconsuming.

Comment: If you need to change keys, `std::set` and allies is probably a wrong kind of data structure for you.

Comment: Having said that, this `iterator insert(const_iterator hint, node_type&& nh);` is probably the insertion function you want to use. The hint should point to the element just after your extracted element. If the key doesn't change, this operation should be fast.